# Continuous Delivery server always asks for a password to the keychain

Tags: macos, continuous-integration, keychain, fastlane

What can I do to prevent it from asking about password for the keychain when app is build with CI.

[image]

If I don't do this, then pipeline will finish with errors.

**Should I add ssh private key and then dialog will never appear?**

Comment: In Keychain Access.app search for the "Xcode Server Builder" certificate and then set it to "Always Trust".

Comment: But it is not Xcode Server... I think. Using fastlane and gitlab runners.

Comment: Oh, then maybe check those certificates for a red circle with a white x, it sounds like the client certificate for one of those isn't "trusted" perhaps. There's also a command that might resolve this as well `git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain`, although I would read up on that before invoking it.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

- Find apropriate item in keychain items and uncheck **Ask for Keychain password**.
- Remember to **Save Changes**
- And voilla!

Answer (score 0):

You can unlock the keychain from command line in your build scripts using:

```
security unlock-keychain -p password ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
```

Comment: build scripts? Should I run it on a terminal or add a script build phase to the xcode?

Comment: You can add the security unlock command to the run script build phase. Make sure the phase is run before signing (i.e. before compile sources).

Comment: Simply by drag and drop the phases in a specific order.

Comment: Hello, I did it, but it still asks for a password. Dont know why;(